# nodejs require statement issue

Tags: node.js, require

I'm new to nodejs.  I have the following files and code:

```
// file: myfunc.js
function myfunc() { return "myfunc()"; }
exports = myfunc;
```

and

```
// file: index.js
var mf = require("./myfunc");
var mfunc = mf();
console.log(mfunc);
```

When I run `node index.js` from command line, I get the error

```
var mfunc = mf()
            ^
TypeError: Object is not a function
```

Why do I get this error?  I saw someone else's code which I paste below and I tried to follow the same approach of trying to get `require()` to return a function instead of an object.

```
// file: index.js from another app
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
```

How come `require('express')` can return a function but `require('./myfunc')` can't return a function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be...

```
module.exports = myfunc;
```

... instead. Quoting [the doc](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html):

> If you want the root of your module's export to be a function (such as
>   a constructor) or if you want to export a complete object in one
>   assignment instead of building it one property at a time, assign it to
>   `module.exports` instead of `exports`.